# Image Not displaying in django getting 404 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I followed official django documentation for image field.I am able to store the image in the database but when I try to display it in browser I am getting 404 error.

My settings file,

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static")
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My models.py file,

```
class Add_prod(models.Model):
    book = models.CharField("Book Name",max_length=40)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images',null=True)
```

My views.py file,

```
def add_prod(request):
    form = ProdForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
    my_products = Add_prod.objects.all()
    context = {
            "form":form,
            "products":my_products
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        book = form.cleaned_data.get("book")
        image = form.cleaned_data.get("image")
        instance.book = book
        instance.image = image
        instance.save()
   return render(request,"add-prod.html",context)
```

Small part of my urls.py file,

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)
```

Small part of my template file,

```
{% for i in products %}  
            <tr>
                <td>{{i.book}}</td>
                <td><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{i.image.url}}" alt="No Image"></td>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the error in the eclipse console,

```
Not Found: /media//media/static/images/644.jpg
"GET /media//media/static/images/644.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1800
```

Comment: `/media` is doubled. It should not. Are you sure `{{i.image.url}}` does not already include the `{{ MEDIA_URL }}`?

Comment: You don't need `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` in the `src`. This is duplicating `/media/` in the generated path. Remove that and it should work.

Comment: Now I am getting this error,Not Found: /media/static/images/644.jpg

Comment: Media folder is next to my project folder,Should it be inside of project folder?

Comment: @Bhanukiran no it should not. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: I am still getting 404 error,media folder is next to my project folder and all the uploaded images are stored there

Comment: In urls.py, I am noticing it has to be - static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) and static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: @ Nabeel Ahmed Thanks now its working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `urls.py`, I am noticing it has to be:

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

`static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Answer (score 1):

Add this code below to **"urls.py"** which is the same directory as **"settings.py"** then, your error will be solved:

```py
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

...
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```