# If else code not working in layout.html django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement blog app with django.In home page there will be list of post."post.author.profile.image" is a path to load image from database.If 
"post.author.profile.image" is None i need to load an alternative image and if it exist it should load the image from database.So i tried the following code:

```
 def homepage(request):
    post= Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    return render(request,'layout.html',{'posts':post})

 layout.html

 {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="list">
        <div class="con">
            {% if "post.author.profile.image.url" is None %}
            <img src="{% static 'images/b.png' %}" class='logo3'/>
            {% else %}
            <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" class='logo3'/>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

After running the server if i click on inspect the path in src of image tag is media/None.The code under if is not even running.Whats problem in my code?

Comment: Are you sure that the images are successfully uploaded in the media folder?

Comment: if the user upload image while registering the image get loaded perfectley.I am doing like if the user has not set profile pic while registering i will be storing value as None for him in database.And in post list if the user has set profile pic i need to load that image.If not i need to load a image from static folder.

Comment: It would be a lot better if you could provide a default image to the user profile image rather than inserting a `None`. So try providing the static image as default to the imagefield.

Answer (score 1):

How about checking if the image exists?

```
{% if post.author.profile.image %}
    <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" class='logo3'/>
{% else %}
    <img src="{% static 'images/b.png' %}" class='logo3'/>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The image from database is loading.But the static image is not loading if the user hasn't set profile picture.This is stack error:Not Found: /media/None "GET /media/None HTTP/1.1" 404 1756.

Comment: Have you set the STATIC_ROOT correctly? Sometimes this also happens if settings.DEBUG is True, and static URLs are not configured properly. 
Refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109582/image-not-displaying-in-django-getting-404-error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{% if post.author.profile.image.url %}
    <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" class='logo3'/>
{% else %}
    <img src="{% static 'images/b.png' %}" class='logo3'/>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If the user has not uploaded profile pic it loads image from static that's fine.But if the user has set profile picture its loading the static image only not the user uploaded picture

Comment: my ans was updated. Please check. Let me know if not works

Comment: Not working.The image from database is loading.But the static image is not loading if the user hasn't set profile picture.

Comment: Not Found: /media/None
[01/Jul/2019 15:30:11] "GET /media/None HTTP/1.1" 404 1756.This is the traceback error i get.Where None is the field value if the user hasn't set profile pic.

Comment: Is image available in `static/images/b.png`?

Comment: check how url formed if user uploaded image then compare the path with your `images/b.png`

Comment: the path for image getting loaded from database is <img src="/media/media/12_nFro3BJ.PNG" class="logo3"> and the path for image getting not loaded is <img src="/media/None" class="logo3">.Where the second media is the name of the folder where its get uploaded

Comment: keep `b.png` on media folder then use these path

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
{% if "post.author.profile.image.url" is None %}
```

you're testing if the literal string `"post.author.profile.image.url"` is None - which it's garanteed to be false, since a literal string is never `None`.

You want the variable itself:

```
{% if post.author.profile.image.url is None %}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 {% if post.author.profile.image == 'null' %}
  <img src="{% static 'images\b.jpg' %}" class="logo3">
 {% else %}
  <img src="{{post.author.profile.image.url}}" class="logo3">
 {% endif %}
```

I still wonder how this code worked .I tried this before but at that time it was not working may be i would had done some other mistake.But this code is working.

Comment: If you don't know how it "works" then it's not a valid answer (even to your own question).